# I want my Cost Table to be Only Viewable by Admin not Employee with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a program that has both the Admin and Employee as users. I only want my costs table to be seen by the admin. However,I am faced with an issue.
In my costs/index.html.erb  I have the following code:

```
<% if @user.role == "admin" %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', cost %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cost_path(cost) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In addition I have also added to my costs/controller.rb the following:

```
def index
  @costs = Cost.all
  @users= User.all
end

def show
  @user = User.all
end

def new
  @cost = Cost.new
  @user = User.all
end

def edit
  @user = User.all
end
```

The error I am getting is "NoMethodError in Costs#index", "undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass"

what am I missing or not getting here?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're mixing `@user = User.all` and `@users = User.all` and then trying to look at `@user.role` when you have `@users` defined.

Comment: @muistooshort I always get confused with this. What would be the best course of action to fix this? any suggestions?

Comment: Call a single user `@user` and a bunch of users `@users`.

Comment: BTW, I just noticed that you have an unmatched `</tr>` inside the `if` in your `.erb`.

Comment: @KenY-N It was my mistake with the way I copied it, My apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing for @user.role but you don't assign any value to @user in the index action.

So @user is nil and you get the error you describe.

As a "placeholder" you could have (in the index action)

```
@user = User.first
```

...and provided you have at least one user in your users table that will fix your problem.

However, you will most likely want to assign to @user the user record for whoever is the current user, and your code doesn't indicate you have any process to identify and assign a current user.

As a start, watch this railscast... http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: I am using devise so I do not have a users table per say. I have already define the roles previously as Admin Employee etc but I am still not having any luck.

Comment: If they are using devise, `current_user` is always available in the controller, so adding `@user = current_user` (I'd rename to `@current_user`) to the `Controller#index` would be one way to solve the problem.

Comment: If you're using devise and you can sign in users, then what your index view should be using is "if current_user.role == 'admin'"

You don't need to use `@user`  or `@users` anywhere... current_user will do the job provided the user is signed in.

Comment: What @KenY-N says... except that you don't need the instance variable as `current_user` is already available to your views.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn So I have followed what you suggested yet now I have a different problem in my costs/index the <%= link_to 'New Cost', new_cost_path, class:"btn btn-primary btn-lg"  %> Is being duplicated. I hope I am making sense

Comment: My telepathy's not very good... you'll probably need to post the costs/index view completely and specify which button is being duplicated.  It might be an idea to ask that as a new question since your first problem is now solved.